# How to replace selected words to another word using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a shell script which looks like this (myscript.sh)

```
echo $squad $buildnumber $date > file2.txt
```

I have 4 squads. I am parsing them to `myscript.sh` from Jenkins pipeline

those squads are:

```
DOD
ABCD
UAB_MS
DCF
```

when script write file2.txt,  then it has to replace 2 squads. other 2 should return without replacing.

I have to replace:

```
UAB_MS, DCF to UAB
```

let's assume if it parse DCF to script. then expected output would be (file2.txt)

```
UAB 115 2022-09-23
```

this is what i tried (myscript.sh)

```
if [ $squad == 'DCF' ]
then
newsquad= sed -i 's/DCF/UAB/g'

elif [ $squad == 'UAB_MS' ]
then
newsquad= sed -i 's/UAB_MS/UAB/g'

else
newsquad=$squad
fi

echo $newsquad $buildnumber $date > file2.txt
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

**Note: I am not allowed to use general purpose scripting language (JavaScript, Python etc).**

Comment: What is not working? Your script has syntax errors as well. Show sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the commands to one line. I added double quotes (no difference here), for future work it is good to get used to that.
I also added `^` in the replacement, so it will only match the start of the line (in `$squad`). That way a string "DCF" in `$buildnumber`will not be replaced.

```
echo "$squad $buildnumber $date" | sed 's/^DCF/UAB/; s/^UAB_MS/UAB/' > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, this should works too.

```
file='file2.txt'
IFS='
'
for what in $squad; do
    if [ "$what" = 'UAB_MS' ] || [ "$what" = 'DCF' ]; then
        echo "UAB $buildnumber $date"
    else
        echo "$what $buildnumber $date"
    fi
done > "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update your script making use of sed in a sub shell and remove the spaces when assining values to variables.

Also remove `-i` from the sed commands as that means editing a file inplace

```
#!/bin/bash

squad="DCF"
buildnumber="115"
date="2022-09-23"

if [ $squad == 'DCF' ]
then
newsquad=$(sed 's/DCF/UAB/g' <<< "$squad") 
elif [ $squad == 'UAB_MS' ]
then
newsquad=$(sed 's/UAB_MS/UAB/g' <<< "$squad")
else
newsquad=$squad
fi
echo "$newsquad $buildnumber $date" > file2.txt
```

But what you might also do is use an alternation `|` with sed to replace either DCF or UAB_MS with UAB

```
echo "$squad $buildnumber $date" | sed 's/^\(DCF\|UAB_MS\)/UAB/' > file2.txt
```

Output

```
UAB 115 2022-09-23
```

Comment: When you want to assign to value to a new variable, I would use `case ... esac`. With the hardcoded `squad="SCF"` you won't have a problem with `if [ $squad == 'DCF' ]`, but it can be safer to put `$squad` in double quotes.